# Converting ASP.NET MVC Project to ServiceStack.Razor

Tags: servicestack

I have an existing ASP.NET MVC 4 project that already uses ServiceStack for REST services, and I just read all about ServiceStack.Razor and would love to move the entire project onto ServiceStack. Right now there is only one controller and view besides the built-in AccountController, and that controller just returns the view and the view is really just HTML; everything else is HTML/CSS/JS + ServiceStack REST.

The only real legacy constraint here is that this new app still needs to make use of SimpleMembership. At present I'm using a custom auth provider to authenticate against SimpleMembership and I would like to be able to continue to do so.

So, what would be the best recommended path to achieve this end? Can I get what I want by modifying my existing project by removing some references, or should I start fresh with an empty ASP.NET app and move the old stuff into it? Can I have SimpleMembership without introducing dependencies that will step all over ServiceStack.Razor?

Answer (score 2):

If you were to start a new solution using only servicestack then MVC would never be there to get in the way. 
I use servicestack.razor and love it.  It is a lot simpler than MVC in my opinion.  Moving everything to the new solution is pretty much going to be copy and paste since what you have works.  I wouldn't hesitate and would make the move sooner than later.  In the end you are not gaining anything from MVC.  You only gain using servicestack.  A big deal for me is self-hosting and eventually moving to mono.

Answer (score 1):

This is a question that will have answers based off opinion so I suspect you will receive a few. I have not personally performed such a migration so this is only opinion but is how I would approach it. However, my recommended approach would be:

1. Retain the existing application/ Given its current simplicity, creating a new app and moving existing items into it seems unnecessary.
2. You should be able to use your existing auth solution via SimpleMembership and use ServiceStack.Razor. I would proceed as such however it does depend on what other ServiceStack features you may use which *could* cause conflict. A ServiceStack expert could comment more on this. Even if that did occur, you would be able to work around it relatively easy. At worst, implementing a simple handler would get around almost all issues from an authentication perspective.
3. Working with different razor engines is relatively easy to do and you can use/enable/disable existing or new build engines via a few lines of code. See [here](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/NcJP200113-Custom-Razor-View-Engine-for-C) for an example. This should alleviate any concerns around dependencies of other built in or custom engines.
4. Consider looking at ASp.Net 4.5.1/VS 2013 (since your project is in early days) as it has enhanced membership support and is moving to a more "less dependent" model of components via the Owin stack [Asp.Net 4.5.1 and VS 2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh420390%28v=vs.120%29.aspx). Katana is a microsoft project that also provides some Owin based authentication components [see here](http://katanaproject.codeplex.com/) and [here](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Web+Camps+TV/The-Katana-Project-OWIN-for-ASPNET) which you could use now and this would remove a lot of dependencies and enable you to migrate other framework with relative ease. Downside is that Katana/Owin has a little ramp up time/learning curve. Again, given your project is in its formative days I would recommend looking into Katana and the ASP.Net vNext stuff as this will make it easier for you and means you dont have to migrate to the new version once it is released.

Comment: Thanks for this, plenty of helpful advice. One thing I am still not clear on is how to prevent ASP.NET MVC routing from conflicting with SS.Razor routing. Is it as simple as removing the routes.MapRoute() call in RouteConfig? And if I am not using ASP.NET MVC routing at all, can I remove the IgnoreRoute() calls that you normally need to put in there to prevent conflicts with ServiceStack /api routes?